# Why style for body in head of site for boostrap template generated with initializr.com

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I recently created a initial template with [initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) for a bootstrap project. I noticed that there is a `style` tag in the body:

```
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

Is there a reason this is not in a external css file? Or can this be put in a external css without negative implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the same as writing an external file.  However, it may be an easier way if you have minimal attributes to add.

<strike>The only difference is this would override any external css file that set the `body` to a different `padding-top` and/or `padding bottom`.</strike>

Comment: **The second part is incorrect.** Local styles have the same specificity of external stylesheets. If you put that *before* an external stylesheet, it can be normally overridden in the external stylesheet.

Comment: @bfred.it You are correct.  I was assuming that the style was declared after all external style sheets.  I will be more specific.